# Erro URI Python - 2588 - Palíndromos

Tags: python

Ao subir meu código pro [URI Online Judge (problema 2588)](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2588), dá um erro, e não estou conseguindo corrigir de jeito algum.

O enunciado é este:
[image: enunciado]

E meu código enviado foi este:

```
entrada = input()

letras_unicas = set([i for i in set(list(entrada)) 

if entrada.count(i) %2 != 0])

if len(letras_unicas) > 1:
   print(len(letras_unicas)-1)
else:
   print(0)
```

E o erro apresentado:

[image: erro de compilação]

Comment: A maneira como você disponibilizou o código não está claro como ele é, mas se está recebendo erro de indentação em uma linha específica e você acreditar que a linha está ok, possivelmente o erro está diretamente na linha acima. Você consegue executar esse seu código no seu ambiente local? Caso não tenha feito esse teste antes, adicione no seu script: `if __name__ == '__main__': sua_funcao()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você quebrou a linha onde não deveria, dentro do `set(...)`.Acho que a forma como você queria era essa:

```
entrada = input()

letras_unicas = set([i for i in set(list(entrada)) if entrada.count(i) %2 != 0])

if len(letras_unicas) > 1:
   print(len(letras_unicas)-1)
else:
   print(0)
```

Entretanto, esse código ainda não funciona por completo. Pois ele só está olhando a primeira linha da entrada. Se a primeira linha for `batata`, ele dará como saída `1`. Se for `aabb`, dará 0. Se for `abc`, dará 2. Esses são os resultados esperados.

[**Veja aqui isso rodando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/U3rY1K)

Para finalizar o exercício, acho que a única coisa que você vai precisar fazer é colocar um laço para ler várias linhas do arquivo. Cada vez que o `input()` é executado, uma linha é lida, então bastaria um `while True:` para ler todas as linhas. Use um `try` com um `except EOFError` e um `break` como condição de parada para sair do laço.

O código ficaria então assim:

```
while True:
   try:
      entrada = input()
   except EOFError:
      break

   letras_unicas = set([i for i in set(list(entrada)) if entrada.count(i) %2 != 0])

   if len(letras_unicas) > 1:
      print(len(letras_unicas)-1)
   else:
      print(0)
```

[**Veja aqui isso rodando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/noedPr)

Comment: Entendi Victor, agradeço demais a ajuda! Como eu implementaria esse Loop ?Ou como eu faria pra apresentar o resultado depois, sabe?! Poderias me esclarecer um pouco .. ?

Comment: @Flávia Resposta editada.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão você pode implementar o seguinte código abaixo...

```
import sys


def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        oc = [0] * 26
        for char in line[:-1]:
            oc[ord(char) - ord('a')] += 1
        ans = 0
        chance = True
        for cnt in oc:
            if cnt % 2 == 1:
                if chance:
                    chance = False
                else:
                    ans += 1
        print(ans)


main()
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/ziymrhsv-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Este algoritmo já foi `testado`, `submetido` e devidamente `aprovado` no site `Uri`, sob linguagem de programação **Python 3**.